# Can I get the size of a repository on Bit Bucket Server using the REST API?

Tags: bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

I am trying to verify the contents of a converted SVN repository in Bit Bucket. One of the things I am using to verify it is the size of the repository in Bit Bucket versus the same folder in SVN.

Is there a way I can do this using the REST API? I am using Bit Bucket Server 4.14. I installed the REST API browser plugin for Bit Bucket. I don't see any API 2.0 references, not sure if I can do it in API 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me with bitubcket server 4.12.0

```
curl -u <user<:<pass> http://<bitbucket server url>/projects/<project key>/repos/<repo slug>/sizes
```

Comment: comes as {"repository":2366464,"attachments":0}